# How can I hide the tuple type constructor?

Tags: haskell, tuples

I want to write my own tuples (for fun and exercising). Is there a way to hide Haskell's default constructor `(,)`?

I tried

```
import Prelude hiding ( (,) )
```

but this results in a parse error:

```
Main.hs:5:50: error: parse error on input ‘,’
  |
5 | import Prelude hiding ( (,) )
  |                          ^
```

What is the correct way to hide `(,)` ?

Comment: Tuples are defined in `GHC.Tuple`, as far as I know, these are "hardwired" in the compiler.

Comment: Deeply wired in. Pretty sure there's no way around that (yet).

Comment: You could always define types isomorphic to tuple, like `data Tuple2 a b = Tuple2 a b`, and just forgo the syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thanks WillemVanOnsem, dfeuer. For now I resorted to use my own pair type.

Comment: @SamuelBarr, that's what I'm doing now. I just thought it would be nice if I could try to replicate Haskell's original way of dealing with tuples as close as possible.

Comment: Even `RebindableSyntax` won't save you here. I think you're just out of luck.